Applying to faculty jobs in universities without a research group in your area
I am doing my graduate studies in a field X, which is not dead by any means, but is also definitely not the "field of the moment" when it comes to number of active researchers. A consequence of this is that the number of active researchers in the area is not so big and, consequently, the number of institutions with active researchers in the area is not so big.
While I am not yet looking for a position, in my free time I have seen a considerable number of universities post openings very broadly (for example "an opening for a member to the Geometry area of the Mathematics department", without any further narrowing down of the expected subarea of expertise), often times including the possibility of an expert in field X.
Nowadays, with all of communication technology, the internet, etc., how impactful is it to be the sole member of a department working in your field? Is it feasible for an aspiring professor to go straight to such a position (i.e., without previously building a reputation in a center with a bigger research group in the same area) and perhaps try to slowly "build" a group around themselves?
I am mostly thinking about positions in the (pure) Mathematics department, which does not rely on labs of any kind.
I have seen "https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/58707/applying-for-postdoc-in-a-mathematics-department-where-no-one-has-similar-resear", but it talks specifically about postdocs instead of an actual position.

Are you asking whether it's possible to get a prof job without a postdoc, however? I can't quite tell from the phrasing of your question.

@user176372 Not really; the way my question is phrased implies it is possible, though I am not sure of the rarity of such an occurrence, and that would be a different question...

In pure math it’s not ideal to be the only faculty member in your department who does research in a given area, but also not unheard of. It can be more or less isolating depending on how social and collaborative you are, and depending on how geographically isolated your university is relative to other universities who do have researchers from your area. (E.g. New York City would be a totally different story compared to more rural parts of the country.)
Being the sole researcher in the department in your area could affect your teaching - the department might rely on you to always teach certain subjects since no one else will be able to or willing to teach them. It could mean that you will have to be permanently in charge of a research seminar for your area, and may struggle to find people who want to attend or speak at such a seminar. You may have difficulty recruiting graduate students. And you will simply have less people around to discuss ideas with and draw inspiration from for your research. Technology for remote collaborations is not likely to be a perfect substitute for such things.
Some people can still thrive in such an environment. But I have seen cases where people who were isolated in such a way were demoralized by it and were not happy with their situation.
In the end, the size of the research group is just one of many factors to consider. As Buffy said, don’t rule out any prospective jobs for this reason, but it’s very reasonable to take it into account.

Nice response, +1. I'd add that this is possible, but it substantially profits if one has a strong and very confident personality (scientific and otherwise) to make this a success. Alternatively, OP could use it as springboard to get more central positions elsewhere.

It also depends on how isolated field-wise.  It's one thing to be the only functional analyst in a department where the closest people to you research-wise is a symplectic geometer and an analytic number theorist.  It's much easier to be the only algebraic combinatorialist when there is a graph theorist and a Lie theorist in the department.  Few mathematicians are regularly collaborating with someone else in their department, but most can at least share seminars and advanced courses.

@AlexanderWoo agreed. It’s a continuous spectrum between being completely isolated and part of a thriving, thematically unified research group. Most situations will involve being somewhere inside this spectrum rather than on the extremes.

Restricting your job search in the current (difficult) environment is probably self defeating and counterproductive.
There are a couple of reasons a department would issue a general call, rather than a tailored one. In particular, they might be anxious to broaden the set of interests among the faculty, either for research or teaching considerations. They might want someone to lead an area not currently covered by faculty interest.
While a broad set of collaborators is valuable for a researcher, it normally develops over time. As you note, modern communication can aid a researcher in establishing and maintaining that circle of collaborators.
Finally, it is also possible that joining a department with few others in your specific field might be broadening. One can potentially gain insight from others with different research interests. One can also migrate to a different area if that proves desirable.

Thank you for the reply! Would you say the response changes based on the experience of the professor to-be? Say, between a recent PhD/PostDoc or an established researcher?

@Gauss, established researchers have a lot of advantages in the market except for places specifically after early career folks. But a department might want someone to start a group in a new area; not a novice job usually.
